# Речевая ошибка: "Научившись читать, было скучно."

Tags: лингвистика

В чем заключается речевая ошибка: "Научившись читать в пятилетнем возрасте, в школе мне было скучно изучать азбуку."?

Answer (score 10):

В чем вопрос? Нужно найти ошибку? Здесь ошибка не речевая, а грамматическая. Деепричастный оборот не употребляется в безличном предложении (кроме безличных инфинитивных со словами можно, нельзя, нужно, надо).

Answer (score 3):

Да, ошибка грамматическая. Верно будет: "Научившись читать в пятилетнем возрасте, я скучал в школе, изучая азбуку".Возможны варианты.